# Read/Write TCP options field

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I want to read and write custom data to TCP options field using Scapy. I know how to use TCP options field in Scapy in "normal" way as dictionary, but is it possible to write to it byte per byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly write the TCP options field byte per byte, however you can either:

- write your entire TCP segment byte per byte: `TCP("\x01...\x0n")`
- add an option to Scapy's code manually in scapy/layers/inet.py `TCPOptions` structure

These are workarounds and a definitive solution to this would be to implement a byte per byte TCP options field and commit on Scapy's github of course.

Comment: The easy workaround I found was writing on for example option 34. I lost only 2 bytes, one for option number and second length.